# vectorised percentiles in pd.NamedAgg

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate

I am having trouble applying numpy methods that require multiple input parameters with the `pd.NamedAgg()` methodology in pandas 0.25.1.

Toy example:

```
## make df
animals = pd.DataFrame({'kind': ['cat', 'dog', 'cat', 'dog'],
                         'height': [9.1, 6.0, 9.5, 34.0],
                         'weight': [7.9, 7.5, 9.9, 198.0]})
##Aggregate
animals.groupby("kind").agg(
     pc95_height=pd.NamedAgg(column='height', aggfunc=np.percentile(q=0.95)),
     mean_height=pd.NamedAgg(column='height', aggfunc=np.mean),
     pc05_height=pd.NamedAgg(column='height', np.percentile(q=0.05)),
 )
```

`np.mean` will work fine, but any version of `np.percentile()`, `np.percentile(p=0.95)` will error.

I could work around this with a lambda function, but I'd prefer to avoid the slowdown inherent with doing things that way.

Any help on how to get the vectorised percentiles calculation (and similar) working efficiently much appreciated!

PS. updated agg, since readers should now be used to pd 0.25.1, particularly given that 1.0 is imminent...

```
##Aggregate V1
animals.groupby("kind").agg(
     pc95_height=('height', np.percentile(q=0.95)),
     mean_height=('height', np.mean),
     pc05_height=('height', np.percentile(q=0.05)),
 )
##Aggregate V2
animals.groupby("kind").agg(**{
     'pc95_height':('height', np.percentile(q=0.95)),
     'mean_height':('height', np.mean),
     'pc05_height':('height', np.percentile(q=0.05))}
 )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you don't need all that verbosity. Just passing a tuple is fine. Second, since `np.percentile` has args, you can define your own function and state whatever those args are, or use `functools.partial` (see below)

```
def myfunc(s):
  return np.percentile(s, q=0.95)

animals.groupby("kind").agg(mean_height=('height', 'mean'),
                            pc95_height=('height',  myfunc))
```

---

You may also use `partial`

```
from functools import partial

perc95 = partial(np.percentile, q=95)

animals.groupby("kind").agg(mean_height=('height', 'mean'),
                            pc95_height=('height',  perc95))
```

Strangely enough, pandas seemingly has a problem with encapsulating the logic in an anonymous `lambda`, which likely is an issue.

Comment: Perfect, thanks!  I do dislike the verbosity, but for my pipeline it is very nice to have an aggDict for `gb.agg(**aggDict)` rather than having hard-pasted code inside the aggregation function. I plan to drop the excess verbiage down to  `{"mean_height":('height', np.mean)}` when people are a bit more used to 2.5.1...